# Insertion sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is the algorithm of insertion sort in C++ (from tutorial):

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int length) {
      int i, j, tmp;
      for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                  tmp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                  arr[j - 1] = tmp;
                  j--;
            }
      }
}
```

and here is what I'm doing in Ruby

```
a = [12, 1, 18, -3, -2, 66, 31]
puts a

def insertion_sort(source)
    source.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |item, i|
        j = i
        while((j>0) && (source[j-1] > source[j]))
            source[j], source[j-1] = source[j-1], source[j]
            j -= 1  
        end
    end
end

insertion_sort(a)
puts a
```

it throws an error of `comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)`. Probably because of overflow.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `C++` version you have `(i = 1; i < length; i++)`. Which means, it will not run the last round where `i = length`. That would be out of the array.

In `ruby`, because you set the offset of the index to `1`, the last round, you would have `i = length`. Hence `source[length]` is out of `source`, so returns `nil`.

```
1 > nil  # source[j-1] > source[j] when j = length
# ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

Answer (score 1):

While @oldergod already answer your question, I just wanna add some fix to the problem.

Here sample of code taken from [algorithm gem](https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms/blob/master/lib/algorithms/sort.rb#L92-112)

```
def insertion_sort(container)
  return container if container.size < 2
  (1..container.size-1).each do |i|
    value = container[i]
    j = i-1
    while j >= 0 and container[j] > value do
      container[j+1] = container[j]
      j = j-1
    end
    container[j+1] = value
  end
  container
end
```

Here you iterate over a number, `1`, the second index of the container, to `container.size - 1`, the last index.